# Open camera directly in the Activity without clicking on button and without intent?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am trying to open my Camera without clicking on my button but it doesn't work...

I follow instructions here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera

Here is my result :

[image]

When i press the button "Capture", it activates the camera but i want to activate the camera before this and just record when i click on the button like snapchat. I think i miss somewhere when i open my camera but i don't find my mistakes...

Here is my class :

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);


    if (checkCameraHardware(this)) {
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        initButton();

        preview.addView(mPreview);
        preview.removeAllViews();
        preview.addView(mPreview);
        preview.addView(captureButton);
    }
}
```

After that, i have the method which initiate the button :

```
public void initButton () {
    captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);

    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isRecording) {
                // stop recording and release camera
                mMediaRecorder.stop();
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                mCamera.lock();

                // inform the user that recording has stopped
                captureButton.setText("Capture");
                isRecording = false;
            } else {
                // initialize video camera
                if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                    // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                    // now you can start recording
                    mMediaRecorder.start();

                    captureButton.setText("Stop");
                    isRecording = true;
                } else {
                    releaseMediaRecorder();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Camera doesn't work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Here is my method which get instance of the Camera :

```
public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("CAMERA INFO : >", "Camera doesn't exist");
    }
    return c;
}
```

Here is the method to prepare the record :

```
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder() {
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    mCamera.unlock();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    // Step 2: Set sources
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);

    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);

    // Step 4: Set output file
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(CAPTURE_VIDEO_FILE).toString());

    // Step 5: Set the preview output
    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d("PREPARE MEDIARECORDER : >", ": > > IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("PREPARE MEDIARECORDER : >", " : > > IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

then i try to open camera before the click with the instantiation but i don't know how... If some one has an idea, will be useful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error. I called `mCamera.setPreview()` in the `onSurfaceCreated()` method of my CameraPreview class.

I need to call `mCamera.setPreview()` in the `onSurfaceChanged()` ! Now it works

Problem solved !

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a preview stream from the camera before the capture button is pressed. It seems that you already have a preview class in the mPreview reference on your code. You need to make sure that it contains an [Camera#startPreview() call when the preview surface is created](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#camera-preview) in order to display live images from the camera. Another thing to keep in mind is that the preview class, which is an android View, needs to be visible in order to have its surface properly set up, meaning you have to make sure it is being properly created and its [visibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) is set to VISIBLE.